Py3DTiles to create terrain mesh
I have a las file and want to use py3dtiles to make it a suitable format for cesium.
Ideally, I'd like to create a terrain mesh, the documentation https://py3dtiles.org/v8.0.2/api.html mentions mesh, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
